# How to remove an Illusory Wall?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, illusion

The spell [Illusory Wall](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/illusory-wall/) is permanent and has no instructions for how to get rid of them. There are many reasons why you might want to remove one, especially if its been there for generations, it might just be in the way now.

Comment: Do you mean ways besides the *dispel magic* spell?

Comment: Would dispel magic completely remove the effect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The spell [*illusory wall*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/illusory-wall/) has a [duration](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Duration) of permanent: "The energy remains as long as the effect does. This means the spell is vulnerable to *dispel magic*." This makes ridding an area of an unwanted *illusory wall* effect as easy as casting a *dispel magic* spell, and even easier if the caster of the *illusory wall* spell is also the caster of the [*dispel magic*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dispel-magic/) spell: "You automatically succeed on your dispel check against any spell that you cast yourself."

While there are certainly other ways that can be used to get rid of an *illusory wall*, this seems easiest and most straightforward.

Comment: It didnt occur to me that dispel would have worked. I mostly get caught up on thinking of the effect as permanent and thus should be hard to get rid of.

Comment: @Fering instantaneous spells make change in reality that lasts even when magic is not there.  For example [Wall of Stone](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/wallOfStone.html) is not dispellable. But Illusory wall is.